# php: How to merge and sum values of the array of the same key value?

Tags: php

i have this original array in my code

```
 [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Cairo"
            },
            "destination": [
                {
                    "count": 3,
                    "name": "Alex",
                    "price": 2000,
                    "discount": null,
                    "distance": 12,
                    "new": false
                },
                {
                    "count": 4,
                    "name": "Alex",
                    "price": 2000,
                    "discount": null,
                    "distance": 12,
                    "new": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Zagazig"
            },
            "destination": [
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "name": "Alex",
                    "price": 200,
                    "discount": null,
                    "distance": 100,
                    "new": false
                },
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "name": "Cairo",
                    "price": 1000,
                    "discount": null,
                    "distance": 100,
                    "new": false
                },
                {
                    "count": 1,
                    "name": "Cairo",
                    "price": 1000,
                    "discount": null,
                    "distance": 100,
                    "new": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

in destination  array, if name is repeated in each object like alex or cairo, i want to merge it in one object, have only one object with name of cairo, and one object of name alex and compute or sume the count key

i want this result ................ ................

```
     [
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Cairo"
                },
                "destination": [
                    {
                        "count": 7,
                        "name": "Alex",
                        "price": 2000,
                        "discount": null,
                        "distance": 12,
                        "new": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "source": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Zagazig"
                },
                "destination": [
                    {
                        "count": 1,
                        "name": "Alex",
                        "price": 200,
                        "discount": null,
                        "distance": 100,
                        "new": false
                    },
  {
                    "count": 2,
                    "name": "Cairo",
                    "price": 1000,
                    "discount": null,
                    "distance": 100,
                    "new": false
                },
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: If you don't put any effort into trying to solve your problem, why should I/we? To get you started `json_deocde(..., true)` gets rid of the objects, and you can use array syntax throughout. After that you probably need `foreach`and `if`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to divide the task into small parts you can better understand and then move up to the whole.

I will help you with the inner array, the simplest task, and you will see how everything will become more clear from there.

So if you get this json collection:

```
$json_easy = '[
            {
                "count": 1,
                "name": "Alex",
                "price": 200,
                "discount": null,
                "distance": 100,
                "new": false
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "name": "Cairo",
                "price": 1000,
                "discount": null,
                "distance": 100,
                "new": false
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "name": "Cairo",
                "price": 1000,
                "discount": null,
                "distance": 100,
                "new": false
            }
        ]';
```

You can decode:

```
$easy_decode = json_decode($json_easy, true);
```

And then create a new array:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($easy_decode as $value) {

    if(array_key_exists($value['name'],$new_array))
        $value['count'] += $new_array[$value['name']]['count'];

    $new_array[$value['name']] = $value;
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

If you look closely you will see you can now delegate to a function of your own in your php code and sum any values within the array with any criteria you like. After creating your functions you could start moving up within the array using more for or foreach cycles.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to sum the count when the names are the same, you just have to iterate over each destination item in each array and when you find a repeated name, just add the count to the previous value. It will give you a new array with your desired output:

```
$a =  [
    array(
        "source" => array(
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "Cairo"
        ),
        "destination" => [
             array(
                "count" => 3,
                "name" => "Alex",
                "price" => 2000,
                "discount" => null,
                "distance" => 12,
                "new" => false
            ),
             array(
                "count" => 4,
                "name" => "Alex",
                "price" => 2000,
                "discount" => null,
                "distance" => 12,
                "new" => false
            )
        ]
    ),
     array(
        "source" =>  array(
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "Zagazig"
        ),
        "destination" => [
             array(
                "count" => 1,
                "name" => "Alex",
                "price" => 200,
                "discount" => null,
                "distance" => 100,
                "new" => false
            ),
             array(
                "count" => 1,
                "name" => "Cairo",
                "price" => 1000,
                "discount" => null,
                "distance" => 100,
                "new" => false
            ),
             array(
                "count" => 1,
                "name" => "Cairo",
                "price" => 1000,
                "discount" => null,
                "distance" => 100,
                "new" => false
            )
        ]
    )
];

$new_array = array();
foreach ($a as $e)  {
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($e['destination'] as $d) {
        if (isset($tmp[$d['name']])) {
            $tmp[$d['name']]['count'] += $d['count'];
        } else {
            $tmp[$d['name']] = $d;
        }
    }
    array_push($new_array,  array(
        'source' => $e['source'],
        'destination' => $tmp
    ));
}
echo json_encode($new_array);
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        "source":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"Cairo"
        },
        "destination":{
            "Alex":{
                "count":7,
                "name":"Alex",
                "price":2000,
                "discount":null,
                "distance":12,
                "new":false
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "source":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Zagazig"
        },
        "destination":{
            "Alex":{
                "count":1,
                "name":"Alex",
                "price":200,
                "discount":null,
                "distance":100,
                "new":false
            },
            "Cairo":{
                "count":2,
                "name":"Cairo",
                "price":1000,
                "discount":null,
                "distance":100,
                "new":false
            }
        }
    }
]
```